# What may prevent my frame from resizing on orientation change

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation-changes

When my device changes orientation I'm seeing the log event for my view which I expect to resize, however the view is not being visually updated.  What may be preventing this update?  Below is the code that I'm running when I receive orientation notification changes.

```
- (void)interfaceOrientationDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification*)note
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    BOOL isLandscape;
    NSLog(@"Original Frame Size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.baseView.frame));

    if((currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
       || (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        isLandscape = YES;
        [self.baseView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 310, 180)];
        [self updateTextFontSize:14 andXPosition:70];
        NSLog(@"In Landscape Mode Frame Size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.baseView.frame));
    }else{
        NSLog(@"In portrait mode");
        [self.baseView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 610, 480)];
        [self updateTextFontSize:18 andXPosition:50];
        NSLog(@"In portrait mode Frame Size: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.baseView.frame));

    }

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I've created a sample project illustrating the issue which is available at https://github.com/propstm/ViewResizeTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using Auto Layout. You can't change the frame of something directly when using Auto Layout; that's is Auto Layout's job. If you try it, Auto Layout just comes along and changes it back. You need to change the *constraints*.

Comment: Here's my example of how to change constraints on rotation: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p256rotationChangesInterface2/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.swift

Comment: Here's the iOS 7 version of that same example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p255rotationChangesInterface/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.m

Comment: Here's my discussion of the matter (how to adjust the interface in response to rotation): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#SECrotationevents